# I can't upload the video to YouTube

Tags: android, video, youtube

This is my code to upload the video:

```
Intent shareIntent =new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share");
String photoURL="sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20120518_165039.mp4";
File file = new File(photoURL); 
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file)); 
shareIntent.setType("video/*"); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
```

When I run it, I choose YouTube to upload and then it will show a error Dialog:
**The application My Uploads(process com.google.android.apps.uploader) has stop unexpectedly. Please try aging.**

This is log:
[image]
Who know how to solve it?

Comment: Try to do your process using Asynch method Since the error which you had written over here shows that the application is generating ANR dialog (If Thread does not respond in 5 sec ANR is called in android).

Comment: I use thread, but the problem can not be solved~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `settings> applications> manage applications> all apps> scroll down list to>my uploads (if you can't find> com.google.Android.apps.uploader) clear data`

That's all you have to do for any uploads that get stuck on sending but don't finish sending msgs.I founds this answer on Android Forum.  The app is called: "my uploads" in my Droid phone settings.